# Attach GPU to App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, gpu, keras, app-engine-flexible

I am using App Engine to build an API with workers to do Keras-related tasks in the background. Due to the nature of Keras, it is more efficient to use a GPU instead of CPU to do some of deep learning work.

I understand that I can use GPU and attach it to Compute Engine but as I would rather to go through App Engine route. Is it possible since App Engine Flexible environment is basically a managed VM on Compute Engine? If yes, how can I go about it?

Answer (score 4):

GPUs are not currently supported in the App Engine Flexible environment. I'll take it as a feature request to be considered for the product.

Comment: Thank you. I am hoping to get that for App Engine for now a lot of our applications is taking advantage of Keras.

Comment: any news on that ?